# How to deploy a database file with a Xamarin.from app?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a sqlite file in my project with some data in it, but I don't know how to link it to my app. I expect the data could be loaded on a Android simulator.

I found a tutorial which was published in 2015, it works no longer, such as GetLocalFilePath function cannot be found after new a FileAccessHelper Class. And the tutorial project seemed using an olde version of SQLite.net-PCL package, because SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid was used in the tutorial project, while this package is no longer exist. Any ideas?

http://arteksoftware.com/deploying-a-database-file-with-a-xamarin-forms-app/

This is the code from the tutorial:

```
[Activity (Label = "People", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity  
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

        string dbPath = FileAccessHelper.GetLocalFilePath ("people.db3");

        LoadApplication (new People.App (dbPath, new SQLitePlatformAndroid ()));
    }
}
```

FileAccessHelper.cs

```
public class FileAccessHelper  
{
    public static string GetLocalFilePath (string filename)
    {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string dbPath = Path.Combine (path, filename);

        CopyDatabaseIfNotExists (dbPath);

        return dbPath;
    }

    private static void CopyDatabaseIfNotExists (string dbPath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists (dbPath)) {
            using (var br = new BinaryReader (Application.Context.Assets.Open ("people.db3"))) {
                using (var bw = new BinaryWriter (new FileStream (dbPath, FileMode.Create))) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int length = 0;
                    while ((length = br.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
                        bw.Write (buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a fixed sqlite file, you should be using an "init script" - basically a call that initializes your db from code. Since (I suppose) you already work more or less managed (or even possibly cross platform) with the database, it would only add a single step to your first start process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to implement an Interface for each platform if you are wanting to call the method from Xamarin.Forms but I will not go into detail on how all that works in this example. Here are the Xamarin docs on the topic of the [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) used below.

For Android you will need to place the DB file in the Assets folder. This is the code you will need in your Android project for the interface that copies the DB and return its path:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(FileAccessHelper))]
namespace MyNamespace.Droid
{
    class FileAccessHelper : MyXamarinFormsPage.IFileAccessHelper
    {
        public async Task<String> GetDBPathAndCreateIfNotExists()
        {
            String databaseName = "MyLite.db";
            var docFolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var dbFile = Path.Combine(docFolder, databaseName); // FILE NAME TO USE WHEN COPIED
            if (!File.Exists(dbFile))
            {
                FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(dbFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                await Forms.Context.Assets.Open(databaseName).CopyToAsync(writeStream);
            }
            return dbFile;
        }
    }
}
```

For UWP you will want to place the DB file in the root folder. The interface in your UWP project that copies the file and returns the path should look like this:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(FileAccessHelper))]
namespace MyNamespace.UWP
{
    public class FileAccessHelper : MyXamarinFormsPage.IFileAccessHelper
    {
        public async Task<String> GetDBPathAndCreateIfNotExists()
        {
            String filename = "MyLite.db";
            bool isExisting = false;
            try
            {
                StorageFile storage = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
                isExisting = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                isExisting = false;
            }
            if (!isExisting)
            {
                StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(filename);
                await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, filename, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            }
            return Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, filename);
        }
    }
}
```

For iOS you will want to place the DB file in your Resources folder. Then this is the code in your iOS project for the interface:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(FileAccessHelper))]
namespace MyNamespace.iOS
{
    public class FileAccessHelper : MyXamarinFormsPage.IFileAccessHelper
    {
        public async Task<String> GetDBPathAndCreateIfNotExists()
        {
            String databaseName = "MyLite.db";
            var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, databaseName);
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                var existingDb = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("MyLite", "db");
                File.Copy(existingDb, path);
            }
            return path;
        }
    }
}
```

It can then be called from your Xamrin.Forms project by doing this:

```
public class MyXamarinFormsPage
{
    public MyXamarinFormsPage()
    {
        String DBPath = await DependencyService.Get<IFileAccessHelper>().GetDBPathAndCreateIfNotExists()
        //Store string for path
    }

    public interface IFileAccessHelper
    {
        Task<String> GetDBPathAndCreateIfNotExists();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to inject the database path within a constructor. We don't "need to" implement such an architecture to retrieve the database paths. Even more if author is only working with Android (which seems to be the case so far according to his question).

Comment: @Kasper.  Any chance of a link to more info on this method.  I'm getting can not create instance of interface errors.  Also you are making classes in the consuming projects e.g. public class IFileAccessHelper not interfaces...

Comment: So I think this should read:    public class FileAccessHelper : MyXamarinFormsPage.IFileAccessHelper

Comment: Here are some docs about the dependency service used above.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning your `dbpath` variable in your Android project with the following (and forget about the `FileAccessHelper` class):

```
[Activity (Label = "People", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity  
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

        // Retrieves the "AppHome"/files folder which is the root of your app sandbox on Android 
        var appDir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        // Locates your dbPath.
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(appDir , "people.db3");

        LoadApplication (new People.App (dbPath, new SQLitePlatformAndroid()));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Where can I find SQLitePlatformAndroid(), the package 'SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid' cannot be found on NuGet store