# Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync and StorageFile.CopyAsync not working as expected

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, xamarin.forms

I need to "seed" my app with a SQlite database. I've used code as suggested by @Kasper in the post [How to deploy a database file with a Xamarin.form app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129861/how-to-deploy-a-database-file-with-a-xamarin-from-app).

My code for UWP looks like this.

```
public async Task<String> GetDBPathAndCreateIfNotExists()
    {
        String filename = "birdsnbflys.db3";
        bool isExisting = false;
        try
        {
            StorageFile storage = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            isExisting = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            isExisting = false;
        }
        if (!isExisting)
        {
            StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(filename);
            await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, filename, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        }
        return Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, filename);
    }
```

When I run this on the "Local Machine" it "hangs/never returns from"

```
StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(filename);
```

If I look at the Package.Current.InstalledLocation folder the database file is there.

When I run this on one of the device emulators it "hangs/never returns from"

```
await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, filename, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

In this case if I quit the app and then restart it the file is now in the ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder so the app runs.

Given the needs of my app I would be happy with a synchronous way to do this but it doesn't look like Microsoft has provided anything but async.

Any thoughts or suggestions as how to get this working as expected?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: **Async** is the way you do it in UWP apps. Don't expect an synchrone API to be released.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of using `GetFileAsync` I'd recommend you use `TryGetItemAsync`. This way, you avoid the try-catch block.
Further more, you should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in your case. You don't need the method to return on the same thread. Eventually, your issue is caused by a deadlock.

```
// The caller of this method may use ConfigureAwait(false) as well,
// depending on the call-site and result-usage.
public async Task<String> GetDBPathAndCreateIfNotExists()
{
    String filename = "birdsnbflys.db3";

    // Check if file exists
    var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync(filename).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var fileExists = file != null;

    // If the file doesn't exist, copy it without blocking the task
    if (!fileExists)
    {
        var databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation
            .GetFileAsync(filename)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder,
                                     filename,
                                     NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
                          .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    return Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, filename);
}
```

Comment: I copied your code into my method. The result is that everywhere .ConfigureAwait is used I get the following error. Error CS1061 'IAsyncOperation<IStorageItem>' does not contain a definition for 'ConfigureAwait' and no extension method 'ConfigureAwait' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncOperation<IStorageItem>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

After much reading about async/await and looking at various questions and answers it looks like my issue was caused by incorrectly calling the GetDBPathAndCreateIfNotExists method. This is being done in a property in the App class.

My initial code was this:

```
Task<string> bnbreproTask = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().GetDBPathAndCreateIfNotExists();
```

What i found to replace this that eliminates the problems is:

```
var dbName = Task.Run(async () => { return await DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>()
                    .GetDBPathAndCreateIfNotExists(); })
                    .Result;
```

I have just enough experience with async/await to get myself in trouble every time I attempt to use it so I don't know if this is the best solution or not. It does work in this instance.

Dave